New image uploading service test
I wanted to let you know that your site is one of the initial few selected for the first step in rolling out our new image uploading service. In principle, this should not change site functionality in any way - and you should not notice any difference before and after, except that the images they upload now have a different URL format. If you encounter any trouble uploading images, please don't hesitate to make a Meta post describing your issue; the moderators will tag those posts status-review, which puts them into Stack Exchange's support queue. We'll be on the lookout for any reports of unexpected behavior.

Thanks for letting our community know about this backend change! We'll watch out for weird stuff.

Some quirks reported on the mother meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/398976/334566 & https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/398978/334566
